# element.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {}) is not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, iphone

I am developing a website, everything is done but any of the events work on iphone.

I tried click, submit, touchstart, everything. Everything works on desktop and android but iphone.

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById("popSwtch1").addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {    
        alert("clicked");
    });
```

I don't get why this is not working even https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html says this will work but I really really really don't understand and mad.

Please, someone explain why it's not working or I'll throw my pc to the window.

Edit: I was trying it with Iphone 5s. I tried it with Iphone 7+ and code is working. But new question how can I make work this on older versions.

Comment: can u check in mac and see the error ?
unless u dont hav mac then u can use safari browser and check the error

Comment: I don't have a mac. But isn't it supposed to work? It's just a simple touch on a div.

Comment: Yeah it should have been but Sometimes iphone done some weird things. U cant complain about that. 
may be ur iphone or safari is old version or something else
so u have to debug and find the reason otherwise cant help u

Comment: If it is don't working for old version no one can develop a website for Iphone 5 and this makes no sense.

Comment: ofcourse can  u just have to compile iur javascript to old javascript

Comment: I installed safari to my windows but it doesn't support after 5.1.7. I don't think to work on this version will be accurate.